# wp_schedule_event action not running

Tags: cron

It seems like all the answers on here for this question end up being a syntax error, however I'm not seeing it here.

I'm trying to setup a daily job here that will run through all my 'vacation' posts, if the _simple_start_date (unix timestamp) is the same date as today, then run some functions to update the usermeta.  The three functions I call are defined earlier in my plugin and I know work since as I am using them multiple other places to do the exact same thing I'm doing here.  Only difference is that this is a scheduled event.

Since I have set this up, it has not ran once.

I am using `define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );` for use with some other plugins I have that are running daily tasks.  However from what I've read, that should not cause an issue with this.

Any help is of course greatly appreciated. thanks

```
add_action( 'wp', 'pto_setup_schedule' );
/**
 * On an early action hook, check if the hook is scheduled - if not, schedule it.
 */
function pto_setup_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'pto_daily_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'pto_daily_event');
    }
}


add_action( 'pto_daily_event', 'check_pto_request_date' );
/**
 * On the scheduled action hook, run a function.
 */
function check_pto_request_date() {

    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'vacation') ); 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $request_start_time = (get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_simple_start_date',true) );

    if  (date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', $request_start_time)){

        $current_user = $post->post_author;
        $request_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_simple_start_date',true );
        $request_year = date("Y",$request_date);
        $time_year= date("Y");
        $request_time = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_total_hours', true);
        $request_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_simple_vacation_type', true);

        update_days_requested((-1 * $request_time), $request_type, $current_user);
        update_days_left((-1 * $request_time), $request_type, $current_user);
        update_days_used($request_time, $request_type, $current_user);


    } 
    endwhile;



}
```

Comment: Using `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` disables WP cron jobs, why do you expect that scheduled events will still be working? Where have you read that `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` doesn't cause issues with scheduled events? If you disable WP Cron you need to set up a cron job at server level that executes wp-cron.php script if you want to use WP scheduled events.

Comment: This is what I followed in the past which indicates to setup task using wp_schedule_event and then setup server cron job.  https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/   
And I assumed that since I was using Disable_Wp_Cron for other plugins that are running daily tasks, that implied I had my cron job setup to work properly.  So yes, I have a cron job that runs every morning that executes wp-cron.php

Comment: So, everything looks OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be in the use of `$post->ID`. In your code `$post` is an undefined variable. As you are inside a loop, try `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`:

```
$post_ID = get_the_ID();

$request_start_time = get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_simple_start_date', true );

if  (date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', $request_start_time)){

    $current_user = $post->post_author;
    $request_date = get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_simple_start_date',true );
    $request_year = date("Y",$request_date);
    $time_year= date("Y");
    $request_time = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_simple_total_hours', true);
    $request_type = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_simple_vacation_type', true);

    update_days_requested((-1 * $request_time), $request_type, $current_user);
    update_days_left((-1 * $request_time), $request_type, $current_user);
    update_days_used($request_time, $request_type, $current_user);


}
```

Comment: ah. thanks.  So if my $post object isn't going to work, then I guess $current_user = $post->post_author; is null as well?

Could I also just include ```global $post``` inside the loop and then the $post object wouldn't be empty?

Comment: Yes, you could try `global $post` as `$loop->the_post()` method setup the global `$post` to current post in the loop. In this case it is also recommended to run [wp_reset_postdat()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after the loop to restore `global $post`.

Comment: great. thanks.  I'll give it a go and see what happens.